# Run code whenever a breakpoint is hit in VSCode/Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pydev, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to execute some code whenever a breakpoint is hit in VS Code (PyDev)?

(specifically, I'd like to print some state whenever I hit a break point, rather than have to type that command manually all the time)

Comment: set a `Watch` expression in the debug bar

Comment: A watch expression is nice, but my output contains very long lines so I'd like to get it into the debug window

Comment: Actually, setting a watch expression that does print(expression) does exactly what I want (not sure if that was what you meant). If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well... almost what I want. It will keep printing when step forward in the debugger too, so it becomes a bit messy. I can work with it though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the debug bar is a `Watch` View. Here you can define expressions that are evaluated when the debugger returns control to the user (breakpoint or step).

From your comments I learned that you can enter expressions with side effects like `print` statements. This is similar to log statements only that they print the stuff when the debugger stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run code if I see this correctly.

But you can enter a Log Message that will print when the breakpoint is hit. Just right-click on the breakpoint, "Edit Breakpoint" and then choose "Log Message" as the type.

Comment: You are probably right. A log point makes a lot of sense, but if I'd have to set it manually it is almost as annoying as having to type the command every time (and add a break point as well, which would have to be on the next line, because I havent found a way to have both on the same line)